# Is it typically assumed that functions are bijective?

Tags: functions, terminology

That is, if I'm reading a textbook, or perhaps even lecture notes, and there are theorems or definitions regarding functions, is it typically assumed that functions are bijective or if nothing is specified is it taken to mean that they are not bijective (or perhaps they can be either bijective or not, depending on context?)

For example, the definition of a function being measurable [at the wiki page here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measurable_function#Formal_definition). The definition says "A function $f:X\to Y \dots$. Can $f$ be assumed to be bijective?

Comment: No, typically it will not be bijective.

Comment: Definitely not.  Bijective functions are very special.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Every single time a function is bijective, it will be said so, either explicitly or by using a qualifier that implies it, like *isomorphism* or *automorphism*.

Comment: I still gave you a +1, but it's perhaps worth pointing out that, arguably, statements like "suppose $\theta:G\to H$ is an isomorphism" only *implicitly* say that $\theta$ is bijective.

Comment: Alright, Thank you. I accepted your answer (it answered my questions perfectly fine), but perhaps edit your answer to reflect Will R's point, if you have time.

Comment: I would consider that "isomorphism" says "bijective" explicitly, as it is a direct part of what isomorphism means. But yes, I  will edit my answer.